# Current drain of a power amplifier LM1876

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-amplifier, current-drain

I'm designing a power amplifier based on the TI's LM1876 and I need to know how much current it will drain in order to order a transformer with such current capacity. It'll have a 500mV@1KHZ on its input, from a RIAA pre-amp and it will power a pair of 8ohms speakers. As it is an AB class type amplifier, the maximum theoretical efficiency is 78.5%, acording to the table below. So, I thought of assuming it has a 60% efficiency and will fed it with +-24VDC. The gain will be 21x, the datasheet sugested circuit, and so, it will produce about 14W@1KHZ/channel (13.78W to be exact) over a load of 8ohms. Considering an efficiency of 60%, it'll be needed aprox. 23.4W/ch, 14/0.6 = 23.333W.
If I am right, can I consider there is 48VDC (+24VDC and -24VDC) powering it and therefore it will drain  0.5A/ch, 23.4/48 = 0.4875A?

Is my assumption of 60% efficiency good in this case?

Can those same estimatives be done for a NE5532 based RIAA pre-amp?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just run it through spice with a worst case input (or do a sine sweep and observe the total power consumption of the amp?).

Comment: I tried it, using a generic op-amp on Multisim and on Tina, both didn't give me a good result. Multisim doesnt't care about the rail supply, it gives out an output acording to the the topology no matter how much is the rail supply, even without a supply.

Comment: There is a spice model for this specific LM1876 for Tina, but it doens't work on my version, Tina8 Industrial.

Comment: The supply will have to provide whatever current needs to be delivered to the load, plus enough to run the rest of the circuit regardless of voltage.

Comment: @GabrielSantos port it to LT spice, much better program. https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

Answer (score 1):

The standby power consumption is 50mA (2.4W). The output power is 13.8W. The effective current consumption is 0.67A@13.8W.
[image: erősítő]

[image: erősítő2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what version of Tina are you using? And is this efficiency factor, about 43% the same for most AB class IC power amps?

Comment: I have TINA 9.3 on my PC. Efficiency is degraded if a higher supply voltage is used than required for a given power. + -20V supply voltage would be [enough](https://imgur.com/a/oCzk1Nh) for 15W. In this case, the dissipation is 20W. The efficiency is 75%. (The theoretical limit would be 78.5%.) If a + - 25V supply voltage is used for 15W, the dissipation is 33W. The efficiency is only 45%.